# Is TrueCrypt creating a big folder full of files with weird names?

Tags: truecrypt

When I mount a 50 GB volume created by TrueCrypt, I see a huge folder with a lot of files with weird names inside. I've got that folder on my HD. Is it possible that these files have been created by TrueCrypt?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I've tried to improve the question. It should be more clear now.

Comment: Are the files located inside the TrueCrypt volume or outside it?

Comment: Outside the volume, but I think I've found the answer.. probably they were created by a tool called ***Eraser 6*** used to delete free space.. If some of you answer: "No, the problem is not related to TrueCrypt" I will accept the answer

Comment: Just so you know it, you can answer your own question, it's perfectly fine to do so, and you can accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the problem isn't related to TrueCrypt. As you noted, it's caused by a tool called Eraser 6.